# javascript onclick change div not working while classes or inline styles inside in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am using javascript to change html content, just for an example I have done something like below:

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="title">
    <button onclick='document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML = "<p style="color:red">semma <b class="mate">Kite</b></p>"' style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cc99ff 0%, #ff99cc 100%);">

      <h3>  Rice, Grains &amp; Flours</h3>
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is not working because I am using a class and inline style in the onclick. can anyone please tell me how to fix this. thanks in advance

Comment: Escape quotes with \

Comment: @MysterX can you please show me as an answer

Comment: One of the reasons you should never use inline on* handlers. Use Element.addEventListener()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here: `<button onclick='document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML = "<p style="color:red">semma <b class="mate">Kite</b></p>"' style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cc99ff 0%, #ff99cc 100%);">`. You did not escape the double quotes. The correct HTML for the button would be this:

```html
<button onclick='document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML = "<p style=\"color:red\">semma <b class=\"mate\">Kite</b></p>"' style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cc99ff 0%, #ff99cc 100%);">
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="title">
    <button onclick='document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML = "<p style=\"color:red\">semma <b class=\"mate\">Kite</b></p>"' style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cc99ff 0%, #ff99cc 100%);">
      <h3>  Rice, Grains &amp; Flours</h3>
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should comment out the quotes inside `\"`

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="title">
    <button onclick='document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML = "<p style=\"color:red\">semma <b class=\"mate\">Kite</b></p>"' style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cc99ff 0%, #ff99cc 100%);">

      <h3>  Rice, Grains &amp; Flours</h3>
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```